# create function for loop oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table **staff**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHtP0.png)

I want to create function when I call function  `select functionname(443) from dual` it return sequence `staff_id`.

*example*

```
1.  select functionname(443) from dual return 863;
2.  select functionname(443) from dual return 864;
3.  select functionname(443) from dual return 866;
.
.
.
n.  select functionname(443) from dual return 6733;
```

and 863;864;866...6733

Comment: It's not that clear to me. You have a table, but you want touse a function to do a query over this table, but in a query from dual? Can't you simply query your table? And what should the return type of this function be. Also, Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: So what benefit do you want to get from a function that you don't get from pure SQL `select staff_id from staff where dept_id = 443` ?

Comment: when I first time call function it return first staff_id = 1;
when I second time call function it return first staff_id = 2;
when I n time call function it return first staff_id = n;
And after that the cycle was repeated again

Comment: How can a function "know" that it's being called for the first, second, third time? And respect to what ? The first call in a day, in a session, in the life? What if I call the function from two separate sessions? Are these two "first calls"? As is this requirement makes not much sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "when I first time call function it return first staff_id = 1; when I second time call function it return first staff_id = 2; when I n time call function it return first staff_id = n; And after that the cycle was repeated again"

Procedural thinking is usually a code smell. Relational databases are for working with sets of data. But what the heck, let's have some lunchtime fun:

We need a package, because package variables allow us to maintain state across function calls. (There are other ways of doing this, such as context namespaces, but a package is the simplest to implement.)

```
create or replace package pkg_test is
    function get_staff_id (p_dept_id number) return number;
end pkg_test ;
/

create or replace package body pkg_test is
    -- variables to maintain state across function calls
    ids_nt dbms_utility.number_array;
    idx number := 0;
    last_dept_id number := 0;

    function get_staff_id (p_dept_id number) return number
    is
        return_value number;
    begin
        if idx = 0
        or last_dept_id != p_dept_id
        then
            select staff_id 
            bulk collect into ids_nt
            from staff
            where dept_id = p_dept_id;

            last_dept_id := p_dept_id;
            idx := 0;
        end if;

        idx := idx + 1;
        return_value := ids_nt(idx); 
        if idx = ids_nt.count()  then
             idx := 0;
        end if;

        return return_value;
    end get_staff_id  ;
end pkg_test ;
/
```

**Notes**

1. Maintaining global state like this is generally not considered good practice. It works here, but in more complicated processes it is easy for state to be changed by calls we're not expecting.
2. State is maintained at the session level. Two separate sessions will get the two sets of data, not one interleaved set. So this is not a good implementation for applications which use connection pooling.

Comment: one problem when I call it but change dep_id, it return null

Comment: @Tiko - the problem with Friday lunchtime fun is it tends to lead to bugs :) We need to reset the counter when repopulating the array. I've fixed the code, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption that what you want to do is call a function to return all the staff_ids for the dept_id that you are passing in. It's an assumption as you are simply not clear about the requirement in your question.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE staff_res_t AS OBJECT (staff_id  NUMBER)

CREATE TYPE staff_res_tab AS TABLE OF staff_res_t

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getdept( in_dept NUMBER )
   RETURN staff_res_tab
   PIPELINED
IS
   CURSOR c_staff
   IS
      SELECT staff_id
      FROM   you_table
      WHERE  dept = in_dept;

   out_rec   staff_res_t := staff_res_t( NULL );
BEGIN
   FOR rec_staff IN c_staff
   LOOP
      out_rec.staff_id   := rec_staff.staff_id;
      PIPE ROW ( out_rec );
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END;       

SELECT * FROM TABLE( getdept( 443 ) )
```